# Json Data Structure Issue

Tags: javascript, json, data-structures

I would like to list data following this structure:

```
the datas that published
today:
data1,
data2,
the datas that published
yesterday:
data1,
data2
```

I will get the data in JSON format. How the JSON structure should be to get the data like that?

The HTML structure is:

```
    <div class="list dark">

        <div class="item item-divider">
          today
        </div>

          <a class="item item-avatar-left" href="#">
          <img src="image">
          <h2>Tyrant</h2>
          <p>desc</p>
          </a>

          <a class="item item-avatar-left" href="#">
          <img src="image">
          <h2>Tyrant</h2>
          <p>desc</p>
          </a>
        <div class="item item-divider">
          yestarday
        </div>
          <a class="item item-avatar-left" href="#">
          <img src="image">
          <h2>data</h2>
          <p>desc</p>
          </a>
    </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

The great thing about JSON is that you can structure it however you want, in whatever way best suits your needs. (Assuming you're not consuming an API that's out of your control, of course).

Will you *only* be displaying yesterday and today? If so, you might want to do something like:

```
{
    "today" : {
        "image" : "url",
        "data" : "your data",
        "desc" : "description"
    },
    "yesterday" : {
        "image" : "url",
        "data" : "your data",
        "desc" : "description"
    }
}
```

Or, if you might have any number of dates that you'd want to display, something like:

```
{
    "dates": [
        {
            "date" : "2015-06-18",
            "image" : "url",
            "data" : "your data",
            "desc" : "description"
        },
        {
            "date" : "2015-06-17",
            "image" : "url",
            "data" : "your data",
            "desc" : "description"
        }
    ]
}
```

Comment: i need to get also these " today,yestarday " like a data in loop so i will put it on list title